# return "even" if the number of strings are even and return "odd" if the number of strings are odd

Tags: java, string, count, arguments

i need help with a simple program that can count the number of strings the i put in the arguments - return "even" if the number of strings are even and return "odd" if the number of strings are odd.
I have tried many things but i only managed to do it while writing the code directly with the strings i want, but not with that ones i enter in arguments.
I need it to start with this opening:

```
public class StringCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args.length % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("even");
            }
                else
                    System.out.println("odd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? `args` is an array. It has a `length` attribute.

Comment: What have you tried os far and what errors did you get? We can help you with specific questions, but we are not writing the program for you...

Comment: Where are you returning "even" and "odd" *to*, and *from* where?

Comment: i have edited what i tried!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the number of strings, as they are an array, just get the array length.

In order to figure out if they are even you need to divide them by two and check if they have a remainder (i.e. are they evenly divisible by 2) then they are even, otherwise, they are odd.

That said, this is not an appropriate question for SO.  The reason is that you generally need to make an attempt at a problem before people here will help.

Answer (score 0):

`args` is an array of `String`s. Simply `args.length` can give you the number of strings you entered in the command line. This is even if the number is exactly divisible by 2.